# Add string prefix and string end to dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add steing prefix and string end to all values of my column of dataframe.
In the beginning i want to add *r'\b* 
In the end i want to add *\b*
I did This but it doesn't give what i want.
A sample of my dataframe is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BStA3.png)

```
 df['col'] = r'r\b' + df['col'].astype(str) + r'\b'
```

Comment: "but it doesn't give what i want" please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i want my dataframe will have r'\bApple juice\b ..r'\bmanner\b  ..My line of code did't give this expected result

Comment: `r"r'\b" + df['col'].astype(str) + r'\b'`how about this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the thing you seek:

```
df['col'] = '\\b' + df['col'] + '\\b'
```

Your `r''` is only notation that the string is *raw*.